# Can a process running in an ECS container determine its service name at runtime?

Tags: amazon-ecs

We're contemplating an infrastructure where a process running inside an ECS container passes a unique identifier to a REST API in order to retrieve its startup configuration.

If we use an environment variable for the UID, it means creating a new task definition each time the service is launched, simply to provide the container its identifier.

```
- ECS service "myservice123"  (some unique name)
  - task definition **custom version required for each launch of the service, to provide the UID env var
    - container with environment var UID="xyz"
      - process retrieves env var UID
      - process passes UID value "xyz" to REST API
```

By definition, the service name must be unique, so we're thinking of including the UID as a suffix. This means the process running inside the container would need to be able to determine its service name at runtime.  Is that possible?

```
- ECS service "myservice-xyz"  (the UID is part of the service name)
  - task definition **standard, only one version required
    - container with no environment vars
      - process determines its service name and extracts the UID suffix "xyz"
      - process passes UID value "xyz" to REST API
```

**Can a process running inside an ECS container determine its service name?**

Comment: How would that unique identifier be created? Depending on this, solution may be easier.

Comment: We have a primary service which launches secondary services to perform some work.  It generates the unique identifier for each "child" service.

Comment: So if the child service has the UID, then does it still need knowledge of the parent? Can't it just call the rest API over HTTP?

Comment: The child doesn't know its UID.  That's the problem I'm trying to solve.  I could pass it in an env var, however that requires creating a new task definition for each child service.  So I thought I'd append the UID to the child's service name.  Hence the question, can the child's container determine its service name?

Comment: How are you starting the container in ECS? Is each container a one-off that you start manually, or are the containers part of an auto-scaling service?

Comment: These are Fargate instances, one-offs, no autoscaling.